# Taranis X9D Plus 2019: Switches SE,SF,SG,SH, and SI are not working/responding on Betaflight

Tags: transmitter, receiver, taranis

So switches SA,SB,SC, and SD work on Betaflight. Aux channels 1 through 4.

But switches SE,SF,SG,SH, and SI are not working/responding on Betaflight. Aux channel 5 through 9, I believe

I am using TBS Crossfire lite, with crossfire nano receiver.

On my Taranis I have already setup Mixers to activate all switches and nobs.

When I first binded to my reciever I did not set up the rear switches(SE,SF,SG,SH, and SI), **but** I already  setup 3 of the front switches(SA,SB, and SC) before binding to my model.

Things I have tried:

1. Connected Taranis via usb mini, opened Devices and Printers on windows and ran through the wizard to re-setup my Taranis
2. Reconfigured my Input and  Mixer page on my defined model. Simply defined each switch in order in the Inputs page, and then on Mixer page defined the channels
3. Rebinded my crossfire transmitter receiver by holding down the button and plugging in my battery to the quad. Releasing the button on the receiver and pressed and held the button till it binded again and  updated again. This time my model was setup but same results
4. On Taranis, long pressed MENU and went to page HARDWARE: ran calibration and also Debuged switches. Everything seems normal

Considerations:

- I have the latest Betaflight-configurator and I am using the latest Beta-flight firmware on my quad
- Flight Controller: STABLE PRO F7, Model:STABLE PRO F7 35A
- Transmitter Receiver: TBS crossfire nano
- Everything else works as expected
- This is occurring with two of my first-build quads
- Followed this reference to solder and config the transmitter receiver: https://geprc.com/download/en/GEPRC-STABLE-PRO-F7-DUAL-MANUAL-V1_0.pdf
- Taranis is in 1-16 channel mode. Also I am not missing switches, all are activated, I checked in the HARDWARE's page
- Taranis Firmware: opentx-x9d+2019, version: 2.3.6
- How my Mixer is setup:
  **CH1 Rud**
  CH2 Ele
  **CH3 Ail**
  CH4 Thr
  **CH5 SA**
  CH6 SB
  **CH7 SC**
  CH8 SD
  **CH9 SE**
  CH10 SF
  **CH11 SG**
  CH12 SH
  **CH13 SI**
  CH14 S1
  **CH15 S2**
  CH16 LS
  **CH17 LR**

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: So, the E,F,G,H, I switches mapped to aux channels 5-9 in the transmitter aren't working in the Betaflight configurator Receiver tab? And you say this is true on both of your models?

Comment: Yes, correct. You are right

Comment: Hrm, how is the receiver configured in Betaflight configurator? I'm not very familiar with the Betaflight setup for TBS CRSF.

Comment: On betaflight, in the ports section you turn on the UART that you solder to by enabling serial Rx. Under reciever you specify the reciever brand(CRSF) and on other features you turn on telemetry output. Refer to link for visual details: https://geprc.com/download/en/GEPRC-STABLE-PRO-F7-DUAL-MANUAL-V1_0.pdf

Comment: Hrm, I see. since this is an issue you've noticed across multiple models, this leads me to think this may be an issue with the transmitter. Can you confirm that your Taranis isn't configured for 8-channel range mode and that it recognizes when the E-H switches are moved?

Comment: What page do I check for if the taranis is configured in the 8 channel mode? When i first turn on my taranis and press the page button 3 times to view the channels monitor it shows 17 channels active, which include switches E-H. It reads the switches when i move them

Comment: The middle of this article: https://oscarliang.com/setup-switch-opentx/ describes setting the "Channel Range" in the Model Setup screen. I don't have a Taranis, so I'm just going by what I've read online.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I can confirm that my Taranis is not configured in the 8 channel mode, rather is in 1-16 channel mode. Also I am not missing switches, all are activated, I checked in the HARDWARE page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was on my Crossfire Nano receiver. I had to change the operation mode from 8 channel to 12 channel. Now switches from SE - SH work. Even though I defined all my knobs, switches, and button on my Taranis, I am limited to 12 channels from my crossfire nano receiver(4 channels for the sticks, 4 for front switchers, and 4 for top switches).

Comment: Aha! I had a suspicion some 8-channel mode limit was the culprit but coudln't pin down where it was coming from. Glad your equiupment is functioning correctly now!